# std::copy : copy is happening only for 1 byte and not for specified length

Tags: c++

Please see the code snippet below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
uint32_t len, x;
char abc[] = "12345678";
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)abc;
copy(ptr, ptr + 4, reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&len));
cout << " len: " << len << endl;
}
```

The output is 49! I would want the output to be 1234. Am I missing something

Comment: *ahem* … you are copying a string byte-by-byte into an integer and are confused that it doesn’t work?

Comment: Why not just use a string->int conversion that's readable and works?

Comment: This is just a sample.. I actually need it to do like this in the actual code

Comment: Well, `'1' != 1` and so forth. That's what you seem to be expecting.

Comment: 49 is the ASCII representation of the character '1'. You are copying chars to an integer. Don't mix that unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Plus does this really compile without including stdint.h and algorithm? I guess iostream might include them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your target is a “container” of length 1 (namely, a single object, `len`).

You are copying four subsequent byte values into this container, which of course fails – in particular, it causes an overflow since the target only has space for a single element.

Other errors in your code (not an exhaustive list):

- You are confusing character codes and their string representation
- You are performing redundant casts

The first point in particular is relevant since what you actually want to do is *parse* the number encoded in the first four characters of the string as a decimal number. But what you actually do is copy its character codes.

To parse a number in C++, use as [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) or, since C++11, [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @chris Yes, since C++11. But worth adding.

Comment: It's halfway through 2012. How many years before the 2011 version settles in? :/

Comment: @chris If the decision was made by me – immediately. But that’s unfortunately not how it works. But yes, I share the opinion that we should just assume C++11 here on SO.

Comment: @chris: I cannot tell you everywhere else, but where I work, where we have true *portable* code that must compile with VS (2005 onwards), g++ (4.1 onwards), Solaris CC, IBM xlCr, HPUX aCC... It might take us a few years, maybe by the time we get a newer standard.

Comment: @Konrad, is there actually a standards-conforming compiler available yet?

Answer (score 1):

std:copy doesn't work as you're expecting. It copies the source 'element-wise' to the destination. So it copies the first uint8 (= char '1' == 0x49 in hex) to 'len', and then proceeds to trample on three random uint32 values following on in memory.

This this instead to see what's actually happening.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  uint32_t len[4];
  char abc[] = "12345678";
  copy(abc, &abc[4], &len[0]);
  cout << " len: " << len[0] << " " <<len[1] << " " << len[2] << " " << len[3] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `std::copy` does roughly this:

```
template <typename InputItr, typename OutputItr>
void copy(InputItr begin, InputItr end, OutputItr obegin)
{
    while (begin != end)
        *obegin++ = *begin++;
}
```

Your output iterator is `uint32_t*`, which would actually cause you to overwrite 4 32-bit words! (buffer overflow). You are seeing `49` because the first character that is copied (`'1'`) has the ASCII value 49.